# select all childs inside class in css one by one on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a map of a country with states, for simplicity you can think of 51 states of USA in a SVG image. All with red color. Every path (state) have a html id tag, and all are inside a div with a class="states"

```
<svg>
<states class="states">
   <path id="path1"> ... <path>
   .....
   <path id="path51"> ... <path>
</states>
</svg>
```

I want to change the color of a state on hover.

```
.state:hover * {
   fill: blue;  
}
```

But the problem is that all the states change color instead of only the onw being hover by the pointer.

[image]

Comment: please add your svg content for reproduce

Comment: The svg content is 3500 lines so is not posible to attach it. The solutions proposed arent working for me workaround is using jquery:

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.states *').hover(function(){
      $( this ).css("fill", "blue");
    },function(){
      $( this ).css("fill", "red");
    });
  });

Comment: The svg is taken from here: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distritos_de_Costa_Rica#/media/Archivo:Mapa_de_Costa_Rica_(cantones_y_distritos).svg

And copy & paste inside an html file.

Comment: Create a [mcve] e.g. limit it to 2 or so states and use rect elements instead of paths. Then you'll be able to edit it into the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```css
.state path:hover {
   fill: blue;  
}
```

check this pen: https://codepen.io/am-77/pen/LYpgNze

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the hover selector on the child not the parent like so:

```
.state *:hover {
   fill: blue;
}
```

Generic example:

```css
.parent * {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.parent *:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>Div 2</div>
  <div>Div 3</div>
  <div>Div 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer isnt working for me. Interestingly this change the color of the 22 state:  #path22 {
  fill: red;  
}
BUT this isnt on hover:   
#path22:hover {
  fill: red;  
}